# Come to me, I'll give you rest

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Have you ever wondered, is any of this real?
> As you lay there, slumbered, could you say that you feel?
>
> Various thoughts cloud your mind, as you wade through an ocean of people.
> Ever alone, you are consigned; look to what you were taught as a steeple.
>
> Near these times of strife and pain, I am there to pull you out.
> See, you have so much to gain, I'll make sure you no more doubt.
>
> A blessed journey awaits you, full of happiness and joy.
> For I'll lift you and make you new, come with me, don't be so coy.
>
> Even if it takes an eternity, I'll be there for you until you make it through.

Hint:

> I have been there for you all of your life, and through your life, I shall remain.
> To take you to new heights that you could only dream of, so you can obtain.
> A place, I am not, though friend may I be.
> My loyalty can't be bought, your case, I will plea.

Who or what am I?

Comment: I first joined the Puzzling Stack Exchange $9$ months ago. I properly checked it out, and then thought it was for nerds. Then, I decided to go back on when I forgot about this site, and that's when I stumbled across one of your riddles (and @[HughMeyers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18924/hugh-meyers)', too) and I was inspired to make riddles of my own. I can't believe I haven't said a big thanks until now! Thank you!! $$\stackrel{\bullet\,\bullet}{\smile}$$ And great riddle (once again)! Adding to **tom**'s comment above, you deserve more upvotes! You got talent, so keep it up! :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you

> Jesus?

Have you ever wondered, is any of this real? 
As you lay there, slumbered, could you say that you feel?

> People question whether religion is real, or whether some of the miracles that Jesus performed are real. Religion is all about believing and feeling what the truth is.

Various thoughts cloud your mind, as you wade through an ocean of people. 
Ever alone, you are consigned; look to what you were taught as a steeple.

> Jesus often preached to oceans of people; as the Son of God, he was human but more than human as well. Sometimes Jesus was depicted as being a church/temple himself (there's a parable about this in the Bible).

Near these times of strife and pain, I am there to pull you out. 
See, you have so much to gain, I'll make sure you no more doubt.

> Jesus is there to ease people in times of suffering; following Him will leave people without doubts or fears.

A blessed journey awaits you, full of happiness and joy. 
For I'll lift you and make you new, come with me, don't be so coy.

> Jesus will lead you to a blessed journey and fill your life with happiness; he also died for your sins.

Even if it takes an eternity, I'll be there for you until you make it through.

> Jesus will be there to save people's souls forever.

Additional hints:

> I have been there for you all of your life, and through your life, I shall remain. 
>  To take you to new heights that you could only dream of, so you can obtain. 
>  **Jesus has always been there for us and will continue to do so forever; only through him can we get to heaven.** 
>  A place, I am not, though friend may I be. 
>  My loyalty can't be bought, your case, I will plea. 
>  **Jesus isn't a place, but he is always a friend and people cannot pay Jesus to get into heaven, though he will always vouch for those with a kind heart.**

The title

> is a reference to a Bible verse from Matthew where he quotes Jesus; and the secret hint is HAVEN SAFE (acrostic); Jesus is referred to has a SAFE HAVEN for all.

Comment: This is it! I was worried that this riddle would come off as preachy, which isn't what I wanted (I want to be cognizant of all beliefs). I've done other religious riddles before, but not quite like this. What are your thoughts on the matter?

Comment: @Joe-You-Know I don't think that your riddle came off as super preachy -- certainly my explanation is definitely preachier than the riddle. That said, the riddle does focus on the aspects of the religious side rather than the human side of the answer (ie. if you wanted to avoid religion altogether, you could have mentioned life details instead of the religious references) but honestly I thought it was fine. Personally, if you treat this as a puzzle, the solution is just that, a solution. It definitely doesn't come across as preachy (see: my first answer for confirmation of that statement)! :)

Answer (score 5):

Are you perhaps:

> God?

Have you ever wondered, is any of this real?

> Many people doubt God at some point in their lives

As you lay there, slumbered, could you say that you feel?

> Some people claim to feel the presence of God, maybe in a dream.

Various thoughts cloud your mind, as you wade through an ocean of people.

> There are many interpretations of God, different people think different things.

Ever alone, you are consigned; look to what you were taught as a steeple.

> Alone(without God), you are consigned to hell.

Near these times of strife and pain, I am there to pull you out.

> God helps the needy and those in pain

See, you have so much to gain, I'll make sure you no more doubt.

> Religious people say they are better off with God, and try not to doubt.

A blessed journey awaits you, full of happiness and joy.

> God brings happiness, so they say. And "Blessed" is pretty self explanatory here.

For I'll lift you and make you new, come with me, don't be so coy.

> From 2 Corinthians 5:17 -- "This means that anyone who belongs to Christ has become a new person. The old life is gone; a new life has begun!"

Even if it takes an eternity, I'll be there for you until you make it through.

> God is forever

Comment: I had to debate about this. If the true answer isn't given, I'll accept this one. P.S. the title should have been a dead giveaway to the answer. The hint should help clarify as well.

Comment: In that case, my next best guess would be rot13(n qernz/n orq) Reasoning to follow

Comment: You're so close with your current answer. The one you're suggesting goes the opposite way. P.S. you may want to google the title.

Answer (score 4):

Are you

> A bed?

Have you ever wondered, is any of this real?
As you lay there, slumbered, could you say that you feel?

> You dream when you’re sleeping on a bed.

Various thoughts cloud your mind, as you wade through an ocean of people.
Ever alone, you are consigned; look to what you were taught as a steeple.

> You fought your way to your birth and finally you were delivered from your mother womb on a bed.

Near these times of strife and pain, I am there to pull you out.
See, you have so much to gain, I'll make sure you no more doubt.

> You recover from sickness and pain by resting on a bed.

A blessed journey awaits you, full of happiness and joy.
For I'll lift you and make you new, come with me, don't be so coy.

> You need a good rest before going on a harsh journey or simply harshness of everyday life.

Even if it takes an eternity, I'll be there for you until you make it through.

> You need to sleep everyday.

Comment: A great answer, but do you think it really fits the hint, especially the last line?

Comment: Is the answer Rot13(Wrfhf)?

Comment: yes! Though I feel kind of bad for Cubemaster. He just wasn't specific enough. I thought the title would be a dead giveaway to the riddle. I came up with the idea after viewing this riddle, https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69469/born-in-a-holy-place/69477#69477.

Comment: I can't give an explanation right now though. So other people who could do the job should deserve a tick. Maybe @Cubemaster themselves.

Comment: Yep, and El-Guest got it!

Comment: I was going to add that as an answer, too. Stupid meetings, getting in the way of my puzzles

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> death/resurrection?

Have you ever wondered, is any of this real? 
As you lay there, slumbered, could you say that you feel?

> Also, when people are alive, sometimes they have existential crises that are eliminated by death.

Various thoughts cloud your mind, as you wade through an ocean of people. 
Ever alone, you are consigned; look to what you were taught as a steeple.

> Death is also a lonely path, though funerals are attended by oceans of people.

Near these times of strife and pain, I am there to pull you out. 
See, you have so much to gain, I'll make sure you no more doubt.

> When people are sick/palliative and in pain, sometimes death is the best way to ease the pain; some people find that, at that point in life, it's doubtlessly a better option.

A blessed journey awaits you, full of happiness and joy. 
For I'll lift you and make you new, come with me, don't be so coy.

> Death and the resurrection is often depicted as a blessed journey up to heaven where souls are made new again.

Even if it takes an eternity, I'll be there for you until you make it through.

> This could refer to purgatory and the process of the deceased ascending to heaven.

Secret clue:

> The acrostic is HAVEN SAFE, ie. that death could be a SAFE HAVEN or refuge as described above. Death will also give you (eternal) rest.

Comment: An interesting guess, but not what I am looking for. It's actually kind of disturbing to think of rot13(qrngu nf n fnsr unira). Think more positively, . It's not either answer you suggested.

Comment: Yeah, I figured this was a bit morbid for this puzzle haha :)

Answer (score 3):

Alternative answer, probably just as incorrect:

Are you

> a church?

Have you ever wondered, is any of this real? 
As you lay there, slumbered, could you say that you feel?

> People often wonder if religion is real...and sometimes people sleep in church.

Various thoughts cloud your mind, as you wade through an ocean of people. 
Ever alone, you are consigned; look to what you were taught as a steeple.

> The steeple reference made me think of a church; there are tons of people that attend church but if you "are the building", then you'll still be alone.

Near these times of strife and pain, I am there to pull you out. 
See, you have so much to gain, I'll make sure you no more doubt.

> Religion and attending church is often a way that people deal with their strife and pain (through prayer); oftentimes priests will dedicate masses to those in need or those in strife.

A blessed journey awaits you, full of happiness and joy. 
For I'll lift you and make you new, come with me, don't be so coy.

> Attending church is a step on the blessed journey, and often leads to happiness and joy; attending confession is said to make one's soul new...?

Even if it takes an eternity, I'll be there for you until you make it through.

> The church is said to be there for all souls to find heaven even after an eternity.

Secret clues:

> Churches have historically been SAFE HAVENs for those who are in need of refuge -- and even criminals who entered a church in medieval England were safe from prosecution while they were in the church, I believe.

Comment: This isn't the answer either, but it is the kind of answer I was expecting.

Comment: I've got one more guess as of right now...should I post another another answer? Is this answer even close to the correct one?

Comment: Hmm, that one is hard to answer. It's close in the sense that you are thinking about rot13(Fnsr Uniraf), but also not close in what kind the answer is. Also, it's not a place. Remember, the question was, **who** or **what** am I?

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> Sleep

Have you ever wondered, is any of this real?

> You dream in your sleep.

As you lay there, slumbered, could you say that you feel?

> Sleep.

Various thoughts cloud your mind, as you wade through an ocean of people.

> When you try to sleep you may be caught up in you daily thoughts.

Ever alone, you are consigned; look to what you were taught as a steeple.

> ?

Near these times of strife and pain, I am there to pull you out.

> Rest helps with a lot.

See, you have so much to gain, I'll make sure you no more doubt.

> You can gain health and energy.

A blessed journey awaits you, full of happiness and joy.

> Sweet dreams.

For I'll lift you and make you new, come with me, don't be so coy.

> Sleep gives you energy.

Even if it takes an eternity, I'll be there for you until you make it through.

> You sleep most of your life.

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> Heaven or refuge?

Have you ever wondered, is any of this real?

> People may wonder.

As you lay there, slumbered, could you say that you feel?

> It may feel like the best dream.

Various thoughts cloud your mind, as you wade through an ocean of people.

> I am not sure.

Ever alone, you are consigned; look to what you were taught as a steeple.

> You learn about Heaven in church.

Near these times of strife and pain, I am there to pull you out.

> There is no pain in  Heaven. Or people seek refuge from other places.

See, you have so much to gain, I'll make sure you no more doubt.

> Sure?

A blessed journey awaits you, full of happiness and joy.

> yep

For I'll lift you and make you new, come with me, don't be so coy.

> You will be new in Heaven.

Even if it takes an eternity, I'll be there for you until you make it through.

> Yep.

Comment: I'd argue to say that "I'll make sure you no more doubt." doesn't really fit this answer. Because you can't find out rot13(vs urnira vf erny hagvy nsgre lbh qvr). I'll say this about the answer I am looking for, it does all these things while you are alive.

Comment: How about (ershtr) @Joe-You-Know

Comment: I mean, it's a type of (ershtr). I'm going to add a hint to narrow this down. Right now, this is way too broad.

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> Dreams?

I'll give explanations in a little while, I'm on phone

Comment: This answer doesn't really fit with the hint. Also, I mention this answer in the hint, so it can't be this.

Comment: Oh right, didn't notice that, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> Morpheus, helping Neo get out of the Matrix?

Have you ever wondered, is any of this real?

> Neo is definitely wondering if life in the Matrix is all there is.

As you lay there, slumbered, could you say that you feel?

> In reality, Neo is sleeping in his pod, not really experiencing anything through his actual senses.

Various thoughts cloud your mind, as you wade through an ocean of people.

> In the Matrix, humans are misled about their servitude as they live a collective dream.

Ever alone, you are consigned; look to what you were taught as a steeple.

> Every captive human is truly alone, but Neo has noticed that something is wrong with the Matrix. This idea should guide him above all else.

Near these times of strife and pain, I am there to pull you out.

> It was Morpheus' goal to pull Neo out of the Matrix before the machines could destroy Zion.

See, you have so much to gain, I'll make sure you no more doubt.

> Morpheus wanted neo to find out the truth and enable him to unlock is potential.

A blessed journey awaits you, full of happiness and joy.

> Emerging in the real world was a journey where he found friendship and love.

For I'll lift you and make you new, come with me, don't be so coy.

> Morpheus had to convince Neo to get out of the Matrix.

Even if it takes an eternity, I'll be there for you until you make it through.

> Morpheus was there the whole time, helping Neo make it out of the Matrix.

I have been there for you all of your life, and through your life, I shall remain.

> Morpheus was watching the Matrix, in an endless search for the One.

To take you to new heights that you could only dream of, so you can obtain.

> Morpheus showed Neo how to become almost all-powerful in the Matrix

A place, I am not, though friend may I be.

> Morpheus is most definitely a person, not a place, and he becomes a friend.

My loyalty can't be bought, your case, I will plea.

> Morpheus had to plead with the other commanders to convince them Neo was the One.